# How Primefaces Push <p:socket> work?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

I am trying to work the PF Push Counter example and I am not sucessful.
I have two portlets.
One is counter portlet. THe other is counterview portlet.
How do I subscribe (register) to the 'channel'?

My code is pretty much straight out of the PF Showcase example.

1) Counter (publisher)
Counter.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>


    <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{counterBean.count}"
            styleClass="ui-widget display" />

        <p:commandButton value="Click"
            actionListener="#{counterBean.increment}" />
    </h:form>



</h:body>

</html>
```

---

CounterBean.java

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ManagedBean
public class CounterBean {

private volatile int count;

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public void increment() {
    count++;
    System.out.println("increment() " + count);
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
}
```

2) CounterView (consumer)
CounterView.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form1">
        <h:outputText id="out" value="What's my count?" styleClass="display" />

        <p:remoteCommand name="updateWidgets"
            actionListener="#{consumerBean.printMessage()}" update=":form1:out" />
    </h:form>
    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(data) {
        updateWidgets();
    }
</script>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Using this example

### [How Primeface Socket works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391190/how-primeface-socket-works)

CounterResource.java

```
@PushEndpoint("/counter")
public class CounterResource {

    @OnMessage(encoders = { JSONEncoder.class })
    public String onMessage(String count) {
        System.out.println("OnMessage " + count );
        return count;
    }
}
```

---

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ConsumerBean {
private int count;
private String message;


public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void printMessage(){
    System.out.println("Consumer Bean Listener!");

}



}
```

Q: the counter on count.xhtml increments but nothing happends on counterView.html.
I put several break points but nothing stops in the Consumer bean.

How can I  have this work?
THis seems to be a simple example but can' tmake it work.
Can you help?

Comment: PrimeFaces <p:socket> is **removed** since PrimeFaces 6.3. Do not use it. Use JSF 2.3 native push via <f:websocket>. Or if you're still on JSF 2.2, use OmniFaces <o:socket>.

Answer (score 0):

1st: what is your ConsumerBean for? You have an application scoped CounterBean which contains the counter that you would like to display with "push". So why do you have another counter in the ConsumerBean?

2nd: in the CounterView.xhtml you don't display the counter at all, even the counter of ConsumerBean.

Use the CounterBean (and its counter) in your CounterView.xhtml page.
In the h:outputText instead of the "What's my count?" fix value use the #{counterBean.count} (the same way as it is in the counter.xhtml).

By the way, check the offical demo, it works nicely:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml